# Dragonvale Arcane Pentournement Wishing Well Bug?

Tags: dragonvale

So the new arcan pen tournament came out a few days ago... And there is this thing called a wishing well with numbers at the bottom that graduatly increase. So I went to my friends park and his wishing well was full of coins and mine was empty.... So I went to my other friends and his was the same only mine was empty!!! Any ideas y?

Answer (score 2):

It is just decoration, your wishing well will have lots of coins when your friends are looking at it from there game whist there's won't have any coins